# Celluloid fails to start, saying "Settings schema ... does not contain a key named 'menubar-accel-enable'"

Tags: gnome, gnome3, devuan, mediaplayer, celluloid

After dist-upgrade'ing my distribution (Devuan Daedalus to Excalibur), and trying to run celluloid, I get the error:

```
(io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid:16054): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 
17:33:53.331: Settings schema 'io.github.celluloid-player.Celluloid' does not contain
a key named 'menubar-accel-enable'
```

How can I fix, or ignore, this problem?

The celluloid version is 0.25. **edit:** Currently seeing this with 0.26 .